# AppFlow s3 to Salesforce upsert fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-appflow

I have setup an AppFlow from S3 -> Salesforce. The Id field is mapped as the unique identifier from the object in S3 to the Object in Salesforce.

When trying to UPSERT a record with a **blank** Id field it fails with an error:

> Value of Id is invalid

I expected that a blank field would indicate that a new record should be created.

If the Id field is **null**, the same error is returned.

If I make up an id like "**XXX**" the error is:

> MALFORMED_ID

How to create a new record using UPSERT?

Do I have to have an "external id" set on the Salesforce object first, and then match using that?